# How to compare the current value of a label to its previous one?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to move the turtles one patch to the right if the value of their label is bigger than the previous value, from the previous tick.

How can I do this?

Comment: please show us the code that calculates the current label value

Comment: to calculate-value
  ask n-of (count turtles * 0.5) turtles 
  [ set value value + 100
  ifelse show-value?
    [
      set label value
    ]
    [
      set label " "
    ]]
end

Comment: Please do *not* post code in the comments - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, your calculation is:

```
to calculate-value
  ask n-of (count turtles * 0.5) turtles
  [ set value value + 100
    ifelse show-value?
    [ set label value ]
    [ set label " " ]
  ]
end
```

So, you have half the turtles increase their value (which is also their label) by 100 and the other half have no change. Since the turtles that increase their value are the same turtles as the ones that you want to move to the right, you can simply add the instructions for moving inside the code block, something like this:

```
to calculate-value
  ask n-of (count turtles * 0.5) turtles
  [ set value value + 100
    set heading 90
    forward 1
    ifelse show-value?
    [ set label value ]
    [ set label " " ]
  ]
end
```